# [ROS2] Using colcon doesn't create any file inside the install/<package>/share directory

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My package structure is very simple:

```
workspace/
           src/
           example/
                        launch/
                        resource/
                        test/
                        example/
                        setup.cfg
                        setup.py
                        package.xml
```

the problem is that I have defined a launch file inside the `launch` directory in my package. But running:
`colcon build --packages-select example`               (where `example` is just the name of the package)
is doesn't move/create/copy the launch file from the launch directory into the `install` directory. So
`install/example/share/example/`contains no launch file, which should be there even according to the tutorial about launch files [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Launch/Launch-system.html). In fact, the line:

```
(os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('launch/*.launch.py'))
```

from the tutorial above, suggests that the `launch.py` file should be found inside the share directory of the package. And this is not the case for me.
I deleted the `build` and `install` directory many times. I run `colcon build` only, but it doesn't create any launch file inside the `share` directory. So I can only use absolute path inside my launch file or move manually the launch file inside the share directory. There is a reason for that? Or is the tutorial assuming that you move manually your launch file inside the share directory?

I'm using foxy on Ubuntu 20.04

**UPDATE:** My setup.py file contains the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup
from glob       import glob

import os

package_name = 'example'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages', ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        (os.path.join("share", package_name), glob("*launch.py")),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='Max Muller',
    maintainer_email='max@infromtik.ca',
    description='Test',
    license='GPL',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [ 'test = example.robot_prog:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

Again, I understood the tutorials and the explanation. *But or our example, with package name `my_python_pkg`, this will install all launch files from the `launch` folder, into ~/ros2_ws/install/my_python_pkg/share/my_python_pkg/launch/*
is exactly what it is not doing!!!
It creates the `launch` folder inside the package directory inside the install directory: **yes**
It creates/move the launch file inside the `launch` directory created inside the package directory in the install directory: **no**

And I don't know, what's wrong with it. Evening following the tutorial I get the folder `launch` but no launch files, are inside it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401351/%5Bros2%5D-using-colcon-doesn%27t-create-any-file-inside-the-install/%3Cpackage%3E/share-directory/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2022-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-25**:
You need to actually install the launch folder to your share directory. This is done in the `setup.py` file. Could you edit this question to include a copy of your `setup.py` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could fix the problem after realising that my `launch.py` file was inside a `launch` directory in the `src` folder of my package.
I realized that the glob function was not looking inside that directory but a directory above. So changing this line of code

```
(os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob('*launch.py')),
```

to

```
(os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'), glob('launch/*launch.py')), # Note the launch before /*launch.py
```

did fix the problem

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2022-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @Joe28965 mentioned, you need to install other files in a ROS2 Python package (e.g. launch files etc.).

You can use this step-by-step tutorial for it:

https://roboticsbackend.com/create-a-ros2-python-package/#Explanation_of_files_inside_a_ROS2_Python_package

Especially part with:

> ### Launch files
>
> Create a launch/ folder at the root of
> your package. You’ll put all your
> launch files inside this folder.
>
> `cd ~/ros2_ws/src/my_python_pkg/`
> `mkdir launch`
>
> Now, to install those launch files,
> you need to modify setup.py.
>
> ```
> import os
> from glob import glob
> from setuptools import setup
> ...
> data_files=[
>     ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
>         ['resource/' + package_name]),
>     ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
>     (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'launch'),
>     glob('launch/*.launch.py')),
>  ],
> ...
> ```
>
> For our example, with package name
> `my_python_pkg`, this will install all
> launch files from the `launch/`
> folder, into
> `~/ros2_ws/install/my_python_pkg/share/my_python_pkg/launch/`.
>
> Note: you only need to modify setup.py
> once. After that, every time you add a
> launch file you’ll just need to
> compile your package so that the file
> is installed, that’s it.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2